# Matlab - size of image

Tags: image, matlab, pixel, image-size

Checking  size of an image in `matlab` using `size(I)`, where I expected the size to be `8X8`, I got the following:

> > size(I)

ans =

```
 8     8     3
```

What is `3` here? And, is my image considered an `8X8` image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

3 is the number of channels in the colored image. That is, red, green and blue. If you had a gray-scale image then it would be `8x8`.

Yes, your image is `8x8`, but a colored one.